# Wubi Error "There is no disk in the drive"

Tags: wubi

It gives me three options "Cancel" "Try Again" "Continue" but everytime i click any of them it just pops back up. After a long time of clicking continue it brought me to the normal screen and I installed Ubuntu along side windows but when booting in to it, it says: No Root File System Defined" and i cant do anything! Please help!
[image]

I tried disabling USB Devices as reported in [this bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+bug/365881) and such and after the install and when I'm booted into ubuntu I still get the "No Root File System Defined" error

Answer (score 1):

There are two issues in your question. The first is the 'no disk' bug already answered. The second is the 'no root file system' message [described here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/wubi/+bug/872614).

For Wubi installs this problem is usually caused by:

1. Minor partition table errors that Ubuntu is more sensitive too than windows
2. An unsupported fakeraid (e.g. 0 or 1+0)
3. A mix of GPT and MBR partition tables, usually from reusing a drive from a Mac.

When you get that error, drop to a shell (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>) and run `sudo parted -l` - that will tell you if there's a partition table error. `sudo fdisk -l` tells you about the GPT mix and also shows specifics on the partition table (to identify what errors might be present).

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be a bug which is [reported here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+bug/365881). Try this:

> Disable all your USB drives, your unused optical drives (with no ubuntu CD), and any virtual drive or cardreader. After that wubi should work.

So perhaps remove the removable disks and see what happens (update your question with what happens)

Comment: Edited the question